# Sql Server Rijndael encryption and decryption

Tags: sql-server, encryption, rijndael

Is there any way to perform encryption and decryption using Rijndael in Sql Server ? i have searched internet but out of help

Comment: this didn't help? https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15296/SQL-Encryption-and-Decryption-Library-Using-Rijnda

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible,
You need to create an CLR Assembly in SQL Server

There is a full tutorial in codeProject here doing the trick:

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15296/SQL-Encryption-and-Decryption-Library-Using-Rijnda

But if you want to make a new one, Just check how to create a CLR Assembly in SQL Server and code yours using Rijndael.

Useful links:

https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/10/19/sql-server-introduction-to-clr-simple-example-of-clr-stored-procedure/

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2kae45k(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [link](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15296/SQL-Encryption-and-Decryption-Library-Using-Rijnda)

Or if you use C# or any other programming language in accessing the DB you can apply [Rijndael](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rijndael(v=vs.110).aspx) in it and store already encrypted value in DB. Also when comparing use algorithm in programming language and compare with DB value.