# SSRS Rijndael decryption

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2016, rijndael

Is there any way to decrypt Rijndail data for an SSRS report?  The data is stored encrypted but we want to be able to build a report to show at least a piece of the decrypted data.  I have searched and cannot seem to find anything that would allow me to do this.

Comment: You might be better off implementing CLR in your SQL instance to do the description, then have SSRS make use of that CLR in it's query.

Comment: *Side note: I hope you* aren't *still using 2008; that version ran* completely *out of support almost 5 years ago. It is long past time you upgraded.*

Comment: In the very distant past, I used Telerik Reports to do this. If I recall correctly, the Telerik framework was able to decrypt the data before being assigned the data source of an .RDL. Sorry, it was so long ago I can't exactly remember, and the source code I had isn't available.

Comment: If it can be decrypted by a report, isn't that pretty weak security-wise?

Comment: @ThomA We have SQL 2016.  The CLR idea may have value.  Do you have any pointers on how I can do this?

Comment: @JonGlazer, please have a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47073004/sql-server-rijndael-encryption-and-decryption

Comment: So, if you've got SQL Server 2016 why are you still using SSRS 2008? Why not use SSRS 2016, which is licenced by your SQL Server 2016 licence.

Comment: Blarg, a question of more or less link only answers, @Sergey . It would be much better if someone actually posted an *answer*, not a sign post.

Comment: @ThomA I just noticed that the keyword for 2008 was there.  I swear I chose 2016 which is what we are using.  Thanks for pointing that out.